# How can I remove junk characters {{3*3}} ${3*3} <%= 3*3 %> from a column in SQL?

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

How can I remove junk characters `{{3*3}} ${3*3} <%= 3*3 %>` from a `column` within my `table` in SQL? There are also other bad data such as Chinese scripting symbols.

```
select * from TableA where ContactFirstName like 'fgfggffggggg{{2*2}}g'
```

Comment: You can use the REPLACE function: `select REPLACE('fgfggffggggg{{2*2}}g', '{{2*2}}', '')`. If you have some pattern, you can use some regular expression, but you need to know exactly what kind of strings you want to remove.

Comment: Tag your database(SQL is a language) and provide some sample data that's representative of the pattern you're looking to remove.

Comment: @NicolaLepetit : I do have around 10,000+ records of FirstName with different kind of patterns. Where I am not able to cleanup data using one single pattern(by regular expression).

Comment: @Gandalf : I have patterns such as    qwqwqwq"><img src=a onerror=prompt(1)>ggg and   {{8*9}} {8*9} ${8*9} %%=Uppercase("injection")=%% within the Firstname column of my table.

Comment: You haven't posted sample data so it's hard to tell what exactly you're trying to extract. Sounds like there is too much noise so it might help to know what the signal looks like